# Entity Framework/LINQ: Selecting columns from multiple tables?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many, entity-framework-5

Models:

```
 public class User
 {
     [Key]
     public int UserId { get; set; }
     public string UserName { get; set; }
 }

public class Resource
{
    [Key]
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }
    public string  ResourceDescription { get; set; }
}

public class UserResource
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public int ResourceQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

I want to select "ResourceName" from Resource model and "ResourceQuantity" from UserResource model for a given "UserId". **Also, once selected, do I need a brand new model to carry only those two specified columns?**

Also note that UserResource model has a composite key so I am confused as to how to make the join... Is this right?

```
 var userResources =
          from r in imDB.Resources
          join ur in imDB.UserResources
          on r.ResourceId equals ur.ResourceId
          select new { r.ResourceName, ur.ResourceQuantity };
```

Comment: can you explain your business scenario bit more ? If you need to use composite key (as a junction model) when you have to have M:M relationship.What is your other model which having many relationship ?

Comment: Hi, my other model is a very simple one called User. The UserResource model joins the User and Resource models. I updated the models.

Comment: do you having code first or what ? Which EF version you're using ?

Comment: yes Code First, and latest EF (5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hence you're using `Code first` you can create your models are as below by using `EF conventions.`

```
public class User {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
   }

public class Resource {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }
    public int ResourceQuantity { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get;set;}
}
```

Then EF will generate your `junction table` is as `UsersResources.`You don't need to create additional model as you did.EF will look after that.

> When using POCOs with EF, if you mark your navigation properties as
>   virtual you can use additional EF supports like Lazy Loading. So in
>   general use a virtual keyword in navigation properties considered to
>   be a good practice.

**UPDATE**

You may try something like below:

**Method 1 :** Method based syntax

```
imDB.Resources.Where(r => r.Users.Any(u => u.UserId == userId))
```

**Method 2 :** Query based syntax

```
from r in imDB.Resources
from u in r.Users
where u.UserId == userId
select r;
```

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: Wow thank you, does this mean I can get rid of the UserResources model? Although one thing I noticed is that you put "ResourceQuantity" in the Resource model, each user should have their own copy of the quantity of any resource.

Comment: @Deniz could you explain the relationship between "user" and "ResourceQuantity" ? is that 1:M or M:M ?

Comment: A user can have many different resources (by differing resourceId). A user can have a varying quantity of each different kind of resource (Indicated by the ResourceQuantity column).

Comment: @Deniz yes.I feel I am right.So You can get rid of "UserResource" model.Try this and let me know if you're having any issues ?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help so far Sampath, I really appreciate it that people are so helpful on this site. I am trying to write the code to return the Resource objects for a given user but I am getting squiggly error for the UserId bit.         


return imDB.Resources.Where(r => r.Users.UserId == userId);

Comment: @Deniz Plz. check "UPDATE" section on my post.